# Memory issue while running Jmeter script against database

Tags: jmeter, out-of-memory, performance-testing, database-performance

I am running a jmeter script against database. My queries are producing huge volume of data as response data(nearly 100000 rows , Request count: more than 30000). I am not willing to limit the rows. So my jmeter instance is facing memory issue.

I am currently using 64gb ram and 8vcpu instance. I have also allocated 56gb as heap memory to jmeter. I am not willing to do distributed testing. If I have to increase the instance memory what should I go for? Is there any way to over come this?

Answer (score 0):

Memory issue [can have many faces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) and you need to take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) to see what exact error message you're getting.

If it's about [Java Heap Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error) - unfortunately there is no workaround apart from going to distributed testing.

In case you don't need the full ResultSet you can try switching it to `Count Records`

[image]

Alternatively you can consider migrating to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), this way you will get full control on how to work/what to do with results (ensure that you're doing the same operations as the application you're trying to mimic). More information: [Interacting with a SQL database](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/sql-userguide.html)